# Could not get Meteor cordova-loader to work on iOS device (not emulator)

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am using Meteor 0.8.3
iOS Device is 7.1
I am using the latest https://github.com/andrewreedy/cordova-loader

I can run my Cordova app on the iOS emulator, but when I try run it from an actual iPhone the app can't seem to see my local server, which is on the wifi network.

I get the following error message:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server.
```

The Cordova app just spins.

I have changed config.xml in my Cordova project to:

```
  <content src="http://<my local IP>:3000/?cordova=0.0.1" />
```

This works on the emulator but not on the app installed on the device.

I can access:

```
http://<my local IP> :3000
```

from Safari on my iPhone... so network wise I think it should be able to see it.

ps. I will be trying out Meteor 0.9.x Cordova preview but I have too many packages that are not supported by 0.9 at this time.

Comment: @andrewreedy I put this question in here as I thought it's probably something silly I am doing vs issue with cordova-loader. Any thoughts, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is old, but I had problems with this recently so here is a hint for others with similar problems:

To run from a real device against your local server you need to do two things:

1. Point the device build towards the server. For example: `meteor build <build_output_path> --server <local_ip>:3000` Remember that build_output_path preferably should not be in meteor dir.
2. Start the local server with mobile-server option and local IP: `meteor --mobile-server <local_ip>:3000`

If you do not start the local server with the mobile-server option, the server will tell the client to DDP-connect to localhost which causes the *Could not connect to server* errors.

Comment: Thanks - I should have self -answered ages ago, apologies... this problem really went away with the Meteor 1.0 release and yes using the --mobile-server params you specified. Thanks again.